# Problems with Earth Engine own function output

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm working on a script in which I need to introduce multipolygons (using `ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon`). To compute the coordinates of each polygon I use [another code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Falessandrobartesaghi%2Fthesis%3AUSW%2BPOLYGON%2BCREATION) and then copy and paste the coordinates in the right one, like this:

```
var multiPolyW =
ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon([ // @ INSERT POLYGON COORDINATES
ee.Geometry.Polygon([ //01
[-77.89253285166824,34.034670313352876],
[-77.8925271755209,34.03465819715058],
[-77.8925420054073,34.03465401840304],
[-77.8926921676259,34.034414570494285],
[-77.89223244114781,34.03454411166798],
[-77.8924084017152,34.034919713939345]
]),
ee.Geometry.Polygon([ //02
[-77.87379641864393,34.237122555657635],
[-77.8737954103302,34.237124499154156],
[-77.87379388200014,34.2371261940267],
[-77.87414857200672,34.23740492522839],
[-77.87421887518978,34.23732696109131],
[-77.87426525762095,34.23723756025138]
])
]);
```

To fasten the project I was thinking to declare a function `roi` at the beginning of the script, in order to substitute the copy and paste with the function:

```
function roi (loP,laP,O,V,d,D) {
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
[loP + ((d * (Math.sin((O - (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / ((Math.cos(laP * Math.PI/180)) * 111.319))), //loA
laP + ((d * (Math.cos((O - (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / 111.132))], //laA
[loP + ((D * (Math.sin((O - (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / ((Math.cos(laP * Math.PI/180)) * 111.319))), //lob
laP + ((D * (Math.cos((O - (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / 111.132))], //laB
[loP + ((D * (Math.sin(O * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / ((Math.cos(laP * Math.PI/180)) * 111.319))), //loE
laP + ((D * (Math.cos(O * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / 111.132))], //laE
[loP + ((D * (Math.sin((O + (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / ((Math.cos(laP * Math.PI/180)) * 111.319))), //loC
laP + ((D * (Math.cos((O + (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / 111.132))], //laC
[loP + ((d * (Math.sin((O + (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / ((Math.cos(laP * Math.PI/180)) * 111.319))), //loD
laP + ((d * (Math.cos((O + (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / 111.132))], //lad
[loP + ((d * (Math.sin(O * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / ((Math.cos(laP * Math.PI/180)) * 111.319))), //loF
laP + ((d * (Math.cos(O * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / 111.132))] //laF
]]);
}
```

What I'm expecting in output of the functions is a polygon, but when I call the function, like this:

```
var polygon = roi (-77.946130,34.213605,315,75,1,139);
```

and print it, what I obtain in the console is the word `UNDEFINED`. So the function is useless.

What can I do in order to obtain a polygon in output of the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `return` a value from user-defined functions. Thus make it:

```
function roi (loP,laP,O,V,d,D) {
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
[loP + ((d * (Math.sin((O - (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / ((Math.cos(laP * Math.PI/180)) * 111.319))), //loA
laP + ((d * (Math.cos((O - (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / 111.132))], //laA
[loP + ((D * (Math.sin((O - (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / ((Math.cos(laP * Math.PI/180)) * 111.319))), //lob
laP + ((D * (Math.cos((O - (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / 111.132))], //laB
[loP + ((D * (Math.sin(O * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / ((Math.cos(laP * Math.PI/180)) * 111.319))), //loE
laP + ((D * (Math.cos(O * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / 111.132))], //laE
[loP + ((D * (Math.sin((O + (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / ((Math.cos(laP * Math.PI/180)) * 111.319))), //loC
laP + ((D * (Math.cos((O + (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / 111.132))], //laC
[loP + ((d * (Math.sin((O + (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / ((Math.cos(laP * Math.PI/180)) * 111.319))), //loD
laP + ((d * (Math.cos((O + (V*0.5)) * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / 111.132))], //lad
[loP + ((d * (Math.sin(O * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / ((Math.cos(laP * Math.PI/180)) * 111.319))), //loF
laP + ((d * (Math.cos(O * Math.PI/180))) * (0.001 / 111.132))] //laF
]]);
return polygon;
}
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/00c9cdc5dc045c14718e19e8182623f3)